# Android - Cómo centrar verticalmente texto en un TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Tengo una botonera y no logro que el centro quede centrado verticalmente a pesar de usar android:gravity="center" y de en Java hacer textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

He seguido este hilo pero no me ha ayudado:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-textview-on-android

[image]

Cada botón implementa este estilo:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_fontSize</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

Los botones están en filas como LinearLayout(s)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">



    <Button
        android:text="7"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_black"
        android:id="@+id/d7"
        />

     ...
```

Como dato curioso al reducir la fuente se va centrando más y más ... hasta ser imperceptible con fuentes muy chicas lo cual no es práctico.

Ideas?

Comment: Es un problema que me pasa a mi también, la única "solución" que he encontrado es darle un margin top de 120 dp o el tamaño que veas conveniente, con ello consigo que quede "centrado"

Comment: El problema es que en el Style estas definiendo el width en wrap_content, debería ser match parent para que complete el espacio del LinearLayout. Si quieres tu TextView no sea tan grande como tu LinearLayout pero que este centrado. Debes hacer wrap content, tanto el Width como el Height de tu TextView y hacer layout_gravity="center" a tu TextView en Style. Gravity hace que se centren los hijos del Texview (digase el texto dentro de el). Sin embargo para centrar el TextView como tal, se utiliza Layout_gravity.

Comment: @Andrespengineer gracias y si quiero centrar el texto dentro del TextView pero he comprobado que cambiar android:layout_width a "match_parent" produce el mismo resultado. El gravity es ignorado (o no sirve vertical)

Comment: Al definir tu elemento con ancho `wrap_content` quedaría ajustado al tamaño del texto. En este caso debes añadir espaciado interno o `padding` en el contenido y así se pueda visualizar el texto centrado.

Answer (score 0):

No es la mejor solución, de hecho *no* la voy a aceptar "la solución" pero funciona.  Es solo un parche.

En values/dimens.xml defino como recurso button_paddingBottom para las dos orientaciones:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <dimen name="button_paddingBottom">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Y agrego ese padding al stilo que heredo en los TextView:

```
<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/button_paddingBottom</item>
```

Obviamente fueron valores distintos y los especifiqué con la métrica "sp"